# Vectorising tokenised french text

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have `Tokenised` french text using `Spacy` but not able to Vectorise using TFidfvectoriser

I tried this code but it gives error

vectorizer.fit_transform(data.spacyd)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()
```

'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing the vectorizer a spaCy `Document` object (instead of an iterable of strings). So you need to first extract the tokens of each document.

Try something like a list comprehension to first get a list of token strings (`token.text` gives you the text of a token in spaCy) that you can pass to the vectorizer:

`vectorizer.fit_transform([token.text for token in data.spacyd])`

If `data.spacyd` has more than one `Document` in it then just adapt the above to iterate over each one.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

french_text = ["Les astronomes amateurs jouent également un rôle important en recherche", "John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie."]

french_token = [x.split() for x in french_text] # i have  just use space for splitting
#assuming your token as 
print(french_token)

[['Les',
'astronomes',
'amateurs',
'jouent',
'également',
'un',
'rôle',
'important',
'en',
'recherche'],
['John', 'Richard', 'Bond', 'explique', 'le', 'rôle', 'de', "l'astronomie."]]
```

now for vectorization part , identity function will pass your token and will not 
    tokenize and pass preprocessor as None, and lowercase = False

```
def identity(arg):
    '''
    this function will return same arg
    '''
    return arg

vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer  = identity, preprocessor=None,lowercase = False)
vect.fit_transform(french_token)
```